# DataGridView WinForms data binding refresh data

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, observablecollection

My `DataGridView` has a bindingsource and `bs` has a datasource that is an `ObservableCollection`, I want to update a few entities in the `ObservableCollection` and then refresh it in the `DataGridView`, how do I do this without repainting the `DataGridView` on each `ObservableCollection` update?

Comment: you just need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface i you need how to do that i can give you an exmaple

Comment: I have an exception "index -1" on select row, when i realized data binding by your advice

Comment: So i found solution to suspend & resume binding with BindingSource object